# Laravel VueJs Vite: Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. Install @vitejs/plugin-vue to handle?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I'm using `vite` in my `laravel` project but when I run `npm run build` shows me errors in the syntax and the syntax sounds correct.

**- my component**
[image]

**- my vite.config.js**
[image]

**- the error that I see**
[image]

> **larave ^9.19**
> **vue ^3.2.30**
> **vite ^3.0.0**

how I can fix that?
and thanks in advance.

Comment: Well you have a syntax error, but without code we can't say much

Comment: ok, I modified the content now

Comment: You don't call/use the vue plugin, so vue files do not work, you should add vue() in the plugins array

Comment: yes right, but when I add it I see the error in the production as I say in the first

Comment: try to import defineComponent from vue

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This might be helpful for future nobs like me. I have also faced the same issue with Fresh Laravel 9 and inertia JS. I have tried all solutions and this works for me.

```
npm i @vitejs/plugin-vue
```

Open vite.config.js and write vue() function before Laravel

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue"; //add this line
import laravel from "laravel-vite-plugin";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(), // write this
        laravel({
            input: ["resources/css/app.css", "resources/js/app.js"],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

then

```
npm run dev
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: It works. But... is this supposed to be done this way? inertiajs.com should do a better job in documentation. It is confusing for us.

Comment: I am glad it works for you. Hope inertia might update as well.

Comment: Thank you, def can be frustrating tracking this stuff down. Inertia should def try to include this in the docs.

Comment: While the error is self explanatory, (@ the time of writing) this small config is still not part of the Inertia docs in the client-side installation part

Comment: How many upvotes should these comment take, so that Inertia decide to fix their documentations??? It's been a long time this issue is not fixed!!!

Comment: In my case I also needed to run 'npm i vue' as well

Answer (score 0):

If you use vite

```
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
```

add `vue()`, in plugin section in vite.config.js

Answer (score -1):

First of all, it's a shame that Inertia has not yet included this in their documentations. It's clearly necessary to mention that you need to do some changes in your vite config.

There's just something else that I need to add to current accepted answer which is running `npm i vue`, because in my case it was necessary.

So, just as @MarsadAkbar mentioned, you need to first run this

```
npm i @vitejs/plugin-vue
```

Also, do not forget to install vue if you haven't already:

```
npm i vue
```

And then, open *vite.config.js* file and make following changes :

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'; // --> ADD THIS LINE
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),  // --> ADD THIS LINE
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

Comment: duplicate answer

Comment: @MarsadAkbar none of the other answers have mentioned 'npm i vue' which in my case was the key. I wrote this answer to help others like myself, because when I tried other answers none of them worked for me and after a while I realized I do need to have vue installed via npm as well. I am sure many other people will face this problem and upvote my answer because of 'npm i vue'. So, it's not a duplicate answer

Comment: maybe you are right but whoever read this thread probably have at least install inertia, vue and laravel so it does not make sense and answer to problem is to not to install vue which is basic and everyone should have know.

Comment: @MarsadAkbar in my case I thought it's already installed which it wasn't and it took me a while to find out about this issue, so with this answer I just wanted to help...