# Vue 3 Vite5 doesn't recognize vitejs/plugin-vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite

I tried to upgrade vue 3.3 to vue 3.4 and vite 4 to vite 5 and I get the next error:  **[vite] Internal server error: Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. Install @vitejs/plugin-vue to handle .vue files**

**The project uses options api**

> ### package.json:
>
> ```
> "private": true,
> "type": "module",
> "scripts": {
>     "dev": "vite --force",
>     "build": "vite build"
> },
> "devDependencies": {
>     "axios": "^1.1.2",
>     "laravel-vite-plugin": "^1.0.1",
>     "sass": "^1.62.0",
>     "vite": "^5.0.0",
>     "vue-tsc": "^1.8.27"
> },
> "dependencies": {
>     "@ant-design/icons-vue": "^7.0.0",
>     "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
>     "@zoomus/websdk": "^2.18.0",
>     "ant-design-vue": "^3.2.17",
>     "chart.js": "^4.2.1",
>     "firebase": "^10.7.1",
>     "i18n": "^0.15.1",
>     "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
>     "mitt": "^3.0.1",
>     "moment": "^2.29.4",
>     "qs": "^6.11.1",
>     "sweetalert2": "^11.7.3",
>     "vform": "^2.1.2",
>     "vue": "^3.4.0",
>     "vue-i18n": "^9.2.2",
>     "vue-loader": "^17.4.0",
>     "vue-router": "^4.1.6",
>     "vue-tel-input": "^8.1.1",
>     "vuex": "^4.1.0"
> } }
> ```

Did someone else had this problem?

The problem came when I tried to upgrade vite 4 to vite 5

vite.config.js

```
import {defineConfig} from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'


export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false
                }
            }
        }),
        laravel([
            'resources/css/app.css',
            'resources/js/app.js',
        ]),
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.vue'],
        alias: {
            '~': '/resources/js/',
        },
    },
    server: {
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        port: 3000,
        workers: 8,
        hmr: {
            host: 'localhost'
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel VueJs Vite: Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. Install @vitejs/plugin-vue to handle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74731469/laravel-vuejs-vite-failed-to-parse-source-for-import-analysis-because-the-conte)

Comment: No, sorry I already have vue() in vite config

Comment: Try deleting the `.lock` file and the `node_modules` folder. After that, reinstall all your packages using the `npm run install` command.

Comment: I'm curious if @rozsazoltan's comment solved it for you. I'm having the same problem, but without Laravel, but with another front-end framework.